# What is this type of camera called?

Tags: 2d, 3d, camera, terminology

I am trying to find a name like "perspective view" of how a camera like this is called:

[image: nimbus game camera]
[image]

It is 2d and 3d at the same time. I'm having a hard time trying to find the name.

Answer (score 6):

This is precisely a perspective view.  It's a bog standard 3D perspective-view camera -- there's nothing 2D about this at all, and nothing that requires a special name to describe.

The camera is using a standard perspective projection matrix with a real frustum, and is looking into a real 3D scene.  Exactly like virtually every 3D game made in the last two decades.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like a standard 2D side-scrolling camera. It just happens to be looking into a 3D world and using perspective projection so you get that slight sense of depth. I've seen some people call this a "2D 3D camera" in shorthand, but it doesn't have a standard name.

Comment: The game space is 2D; the graphics are regular 3D graphics.  So I would say a 3D camera and a 2D world viewed from the side.

Comment: Agree and I'd say there's no single term that encompasses this camera style. **Perspective** (as opposed to orthographic etc.) describes the projection, and **side-scrolling** (as opposed to top-down, first-person, over-the-shoulder etc.) describes the orientation.

Comment: game space is 2D, but the graphics space is full 3D, so it seems like a regular 3D world with 3D camera to me, regardless of in what dimensions you are playing :D

Answer (score 1):

Games like that are often termed [2.5D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D) and therefore I may be tempted to refer to that camera as a 2.5D side scrolling camera.

Sadly this term can mean a 2D game made to give the illusion of 3D as well as a 3D game that is designed to play and/or look like a 2D game (as in the question's example). However, in both cases the camera is usually locked to a single orientation. So I may also be tempted to call it a "fixed orientation" camera instead.

Games such as Trials Evolution can also be described as 2.5D and are a slight exception to this naming. While the orientation is still fixed, it is only fixed with relation to the track which doesn't have to be fixed to a single plane.

So with all that said, I don't think there is a particularly good name for that kind of camera other than calling it a "Perspective camera with restricted degrees of freedom" or "Fixed orientation perspective camera" or maybe call it a "perspective camera" when detailing it's view type and a "side scrolling camera" when talking about it's movement.

Comment: 2.5D is an ***incredibly*** vague term. Ray-casting games like Wolfenstein 3D, Doom and Duke Nukem 3D are called 2.5D and their cameras are nothing at all like this game. So it is good that you resisted that temptation ;) Frankly I hate the term 2.5D to begin with; might as well classify games by the degrees of freedom in their camera.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman - agreed, it isn't a good term. I've never heard anyone call those games 2.5D though, only the specific character billboarding technique they use.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Interesting that you should say that - while I recall hearing the version you're mentioning, I don't think I've heard the word used that way in roughly the last decade, as those engines fell out of necessity - but I've heard it used regularly in recent memory to describe this sort of '3d visual for 2d gameplay' look.

Answer (score 0):

From that image, I see the game world as 3D:

This is a 3D rendering camera, set as Perspective in a 3D world but with a strict 90° or similar angle depending on orientation (axis and local).

Answer (score -2):

I believe it is an orthographic camera you are looking for.

Comment: I think this is wrong. It looks very much like a perspective camera. Orthographic cameras look very 2D.